# getElementByName validation

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

I know how to get fields to validate with JavaScript using methods such as getElementById etc. For this instance I need to use the getElementByName method. I have the error `'Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of null` in console.log.

Here is code that I used with the getElementByName method which worked

### HTML

```
<button name="button1">Hello</button>
<div class="form-row">    
            <div class="field w100">    
                <label for="primary_phone">Primary phone (digits only) *</label>
                <input type="text" name="primary_phone" id="primary_phone" placeholder="hello"></input>

        </div>
    </div>   
    <div class="form-row">      
        <label for="confirm_phone">Confirm phone (digits only) *</label>
        <input type="text" name="confirm_phone" id="confirm_phone"></input>    
    </div> 
  </div>
```

## JavaScript

```
var btn1 = document.getElementsByName('button1')[0];
var btn1Text = btn1.firstChild.nodeValue;
console.log(btn1Text);
```

Below is the code that is returning the error.

### HTML

```
<button id="button">Button</button>
```

### JavaScript

```
function validate() {

    var primaryNo = document.getElementsByName('primary_phone')[0];
    var confirmNo = document.getElementsByName('confirm_phone')[0];
    var primaryValue = primaryNo.firstChild.nodeValue;
    var confirmValue = confirmNo.firstChild.nodeValue;

        if (primaryValue !== confirmValue) {
            alert('Numbers do not match');
        } else {
            alert('congratulations')
        }
};

var btn = document.getElementById('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', validate, false);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `var primaryValue = primaryNo.value;`

Comment: Can you share the relevant html also

Comment: can you provide us the complete html code ? are you sure that "primary_phone" and "confirm_phone" exist in your code as name attribute ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny was right with the input value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might be having `input` fields whose value you are trying to fetch.

In that case, they don't have any child elements, instead you need to get their `value` like

```
var primaryValue = primaryNo.value;
var confirmValue = confirmNo.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the result of
var btn1 = document.getElementsByName('button1')[0];
in console (console.log(btn1);) ?

Be careful with tag names: button, button1... maybe you have a syntax mistake.